# I'm new to Python and managed to crash IDLE after adding a line of code to my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash, python-idle

I'm working on a small game and, in the interest of full disclosure, I've learned some other languages before but this is only my second day learning Python.

What I was trying to do was simple enough: I was trying to generate a random integer between two integer values (e.g. random(a,b)). I looked around to see if there was an existing function that I could use, and I found information about a function called "randint". So I added a line of code to my program that looked something like:

```
value = randint(1,15)
```

I received an error that randint was undefined. So then I looked further and saw someone state that I needed to import the random library using the following line of code:

```
import random
```

The moment I refreshed (F5) IDLE crashed. So then I figured "welp, that was wrong" and I went to open IDLE and make the change. I was able to open IDLE, but I can't open the file. In fact, I can't open any of the (three) files that I've made. I opened the file in Notepad++ and removed the offending lines (both randint and import random), but IDLE still crashes whenever I try to open a file. I rebooted my laptop for lack of a better idea, but there was no change in behavior.

Details: Windows 7 x64 w/ all updates, Python 3.2.3.

...help? Also, what did I do? :-/

Comment: try `import random` instead of important.

Comment: that's a very important question

Comment: If using `important` instead of `import` crashed the IDE, then you should probably submit a bug-report to the IDLE project.

Comment: 1.  correct syntax is important
2.  correct syntax is not important

Comment: I didn't know you can crash IDLE by typing in code that does not conform to the language... He may have found a new exploit :).

Comment: What are your files called? Maybe you've named them after something from the Python library

Comment: The files are JumpingJupiters.py, Day1.py, and testing.py. The last file I made to see if I could open new files: although it let me create the file, it still crashed. (That file only has a single line in it, and that's:
# test file

Comment: @Quintessence Are you getting an I/O error when you try to open the files? That could be signs of a bad hard drive. You might have downloaded the 32 bit version of Python, I would recommend uninstalling idle and installing [Python 3.3](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/python-3.3.0.amd64.msi)

Comment: In addition, please paste your *entire* code so that we can replicate the bug. Next, open **My Computer** and type in: `Control Panel\System and Security\Action Center\Reliability Monitor` You should find an error report for Python/IDLE. Also paste that in.

Comment: I cross-posted to another forum and was able to get IDLE working again by running it from terminal. It opened the program and when I opened the file it stayed open and showed an error in terminal and I was immediately prompted to save the file (...again). Now IDLE works normally and lets me open all of my files. It was such a bizarre issue.  Thank you for all the input :)

Answer (score 1):

Received a solution from another forum:

"If you want to try diagnosing the problem, run the Python command line and then enter the line:

`from idlelib import idle`

That will launch idle, and you should get a traceback in the command prompt if something goes wrong."

When I did this it opened IDLE and produced an error (displayed in terminal) when I tried to open the file. Rather than crashing, I received a prompt (pop-up, not in terminal) to save the file. I found this odd because I had just opened it and hadn't made any changes. I let it save the file and then success! Now I can use IDLE to open any of my files again. Hope this helps someone else who encounters this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but based on my experience, IDLE was never reliable enough for me. Practice using the command-line Python instead.

1. Go to the command prompt by running `cmd`
2. `cd` into your file's directory
3. type `python yourfilename.py`